# Get overloaded value from descendant class in constructor

Tags: typescript

I have some ancestor class where I want to use overloaded variables from its descendant classes.

```js
class Base {
    model: string;
    constructor() {
       // I would like to get custom value from descendant class in constructor
       console.log(this.model);
    }
}
```

and descendant class with overloaded variable

```js
class Anything extends Base {
    // overload variable model
    model: string = "WOOOOW";
}
```

and after

```js
new Anything();
```

it logs `undefined`.

---

Is it possible to access overloaded variables in constructor in TS/JS as it is possible for example in PHP?
*If it is not possible - What's the best partice?*